# How to replace "wp-content/blogs.dir" with "media" for attachment permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, attachments

How to replace "wp-content/blogs.dir" with "media" for attachment permalinks in a multisite environment?

This is how links look now:

http://url.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/21/files/2011/06/650026_x640_21.jpg
*-or-*
http://subdomain.url.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/21/files/2011/06/650026_x640_21.jpg

Ideally this is how the would look:

http://url.com/media/2011/06/650026_x640_21.jpg
*-or-*
http://subdomain.url.com/media/2011/06/650026_x640_21.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the code you are using to extract the initial URL?

Comment: I'm using a [gallery] template tag.

Comment: Next Gen Gallery?

Comment: Just the basic WP Gallery short-tag.

Comment: Do you have pretty permalinks turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually ... the `blogs.dir` part isn't used except for internally.

Let's say you have a network with two sites - `http://url.com` and `http://sub.url.com`.  The files will be located in (respectively):

- `http://url.com/files/2011/06/...`
- `http://sub.url.com/files/2011/06/...`

The `blogs.dir` directory is where the images exist physically, yes, but your `.htaccess` file is routing the virtual directories I just listed above to the correct location.

I'm guessing you're manually putting together the URLs you reference above ... because that's not how Multisite is set up to work by default.

---

### Update

I just tested this on my own network installation to give you a specific example.

My main blog is http://mindsharestrategy.com (custom domain mapped to a subdomain network installation - http://business.eamann.com is the same site).  A recent post with images: [How to Publish a WordPress Plugin - Subversion](http://mindsharestrategy.com/2011/how-to-publish-a-wordpress-plugin-subversion/).

The first image in the post is: http://mindsharestrategy.com/files/2011/05/checkout.png

But an alternate link that *also* works: http://eamann.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2011/05/checkout.png

WordPress automatically maps the `/files` directory for this site to `/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files` via the `.htaccess` file.

So your image permalinks will work with the shortened version ... there's nothing you need to do there.  It sounds like your problem is actually with the way the `[gallery]` shortcode outputs content.

Comment: Not much of an answer ;)

Comment: That's how its working for me, I'm not making it up. :)

`<!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php --> 
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-476 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-photostream'><dl class='gallery-item'><dt class='gallery-icon'><a href='http://sub.url.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/21/files/2011/06/650026_x640_21.jpg' title='650026_x640_21'><img width="143" height="107" src="http://sub.url.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/21/files/2011/06/650026_x640_21-143x107.jpg" class="attachment-photostream" alt="650026_x640_21" title="650026_x640_21" /></a></dt></dl>`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Your site shouldn't be using /wp-content/blogs.dir at all. That gets replaced with /files in a multisite setup.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into core:

```
/wp-includes/ms-default-constants.php > line 21 : UPLOADBLOGSDIR
/wp-includes/ms-default-constants.php > line 27, 28 : BLOGUPLOADDIR
/wp-admin/includes/ms.php > line 91 ; apply_filters( 'wpmu_delete_blog_upload_dir', WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/blogs.dir/{$blog_id}/files/", $blog_id );
```

I don't know much about WPMU/Network installs, that's such what come up from a cross file search.